# Change the status after click button and send email to notify the user

Tags: email, button, notifications, rules

currently i am doing the recruitment system by using drupal 7 where the applicant can apply the job and HR admin can shortlist the applicant.

i have created "shortlist button" in content type to let the HR admin change the applicant status from pending (by default) to shortlisted.
i put some rules to change the user status.

so my question is, how i want to send the email to notify the user after HR admin click the "shortlist button" to inform the user that they has been shortlisted.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use another rule that triggers when a Node is saved. You'll want the following conditions:

- Node type is Application (or whatever you have it named)
- You'll then want to check that your shortlist field contains 'shortlisted' by using the Data Comparison condition.
- To avoid triggering this rule every time that node is saved, you'll again want the check the shortlisted field with data comparison, but this time use the "node-unchanged" selector to check for "shortlisted", and negate the condition.

Then create an action to send an email to the user.

This will make it so that when you save the node, it checks that the shortlist field was just changed the "shortlisted" and send an email to the user. If you don't add the second "negate" condition, it will send an email every time that node is saved and "shortlisted" is selected - so make sure you add it.